# How to Log all Messages into a channel (discord.py)

Tags: discord, discord.py

Hey there im new to discord.py and i want to know if theres a way to log all messages that are send in a server into a  channel. (My bot is in the server yes)

Example someone sends a message in  a server my bot logs the message and sends it into a channel

Comment: There is a way, but we don't code here for others, you need to show that at least you tried, put some code in the question, what have you tried so far, why don't your current solutions work... etc

Comment: You should have a look at the [discord.py documentaion](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io), more specifically at the [on_message()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message) event.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using comments to explain the code, so read them carefully.

```py
# this event will be triggered whenever a message is received
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    # log is a coroutine, so don't forget to await the call
    await log(msg)
    # to avoid 'commands not working'
    client.process_commands(msg)

async def log(msg):
    # get the guild from the message
    guild = msg.guild
    # find the channel with name 'logs'
    log_channel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name="logs")
    try:
        # if the channel exists and the bot has permissions to send messages in 'logs' channel, 
        # this will pass, else an exception will be thrown
        await log_channel.send("*{0.content}*, sent by **{0.author.nick}**, in **msg.channel.name**".format(msg))
    except Exception:
        # exceptions will be raised if any of those said above, are missing
        print("'logs' channel not found, or bot missing permissions")
```